# Upload a new file to a file share using FileWebRequest

Tags: c#, file-upload

I'm trying to use C#'s FileWebRequest to create a new directory on a file share and upload a new file to that directory. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I can successfully upload a new file if it sits directly in the file share, but when I try to upload it inside a new directory, I get an exception.

For example, uploading *newfile.txt* to this location works fine:
*\\servername\sharename\newfile.txt*

But if I try to upload it to this location: *\\servername\sharename\**newfolder**\newfile.txt'.*

...then I get an exception: *Could not find a part of the path \\servername\sharename\newfolder\newfile.txt'.*

Background:

I have a web service that needs to generate a file and copy it to a file share. For security reasons, the web service impersonates the specific users who initiate the generation requests, and it needs to copy the file to the share using these (delegated) impersonated identities.

Apparently delegating the impersonated user identity from the web service to the file system doesn't work as-is, so instead, I'm attempting to use the FileWebRequest to upload the file using the URI of the share, so I can use the AuthenticationManager.CustomTargetNameDictionary to register the SPN of the file server so delegation can be achieved.

EDIT: I'm currently using the FileWebRequest to upload the file thus:

```
var uploadRequest = (FileWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"file://servername/sharename/newfolder/newfile.txt");
//...snip
using (var outputStream = uploadRequest.GetRequestStream())
{
    outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried checking whether **newfolder** exists and creating it if not?

Comment: Thanks Omada - how would I do that with FileWebRequest? I can't use File.Exists because of the delegated permissions issue I've mentioned in the original post.